# Google My Business API deprecation: Replacement for fetching user reviews?

Tags: google-api, google-my-business-api

I've been using the Google My Business API v4.x to fetch information about my My Business locations (especially user reviews and questions&answers).

According to https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations Google will deprecate/sunset the Google MyBusiness API.

[image: Google Deprecation Schedule]

The above document by Google specifies replacement APIs for some of the data previously available in My Business API v4.x, for example:

- Account Management API v1
- Questions API v1
- Business Information API v1

I managed to move to the new APIs for most of my use cases. **Unfortunately, it seems there is no replacement for fetching the user reviews of a specific location** and I cannot find anything in the API documentation or the C# API client libraries that mention user reviews.

Am I missing something? Has support for user reviews been dropped silently?

I found that the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#PlaceReview) may grant access to user reviews of places. Are these the same user reviews that can be found in My Business? I only need user reviews of my My Business locations, not random places in Google Maps - so this seems like overkill for my use case, even not counting the additional costs?

Comment: Thank you for the link - yes :) Weird that I was not able to find this answer in my searches, but thanks a lot!

Comment: I just ran into this and wanted to share what I had to do.

Comment: I am using the Java client fyi...

1) Initializ/Use MyBusinessAccountManagement (v1) to grab accounts

...
MyBusinessAccountManagement mgmt = new MyBusinessAccountManagement.Builder(httpTransport, JsonFactoryUtil.getFactory(), creds).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
MyBusinessAccountManagement.Accounts mgmtAccounts = mgmt.accounts();
MyBusinessAccountManagement.Accounts.List mgmtAccountsList = mgmtAccounts.list();
ListAccountsResponse mgmtAccountsListResp = mgmtAccountsList.execute();
...

Comment: 2) Initialize MyBusinessBusinessInformation (v1) objects

..
MyBusinessBusinessInformation mybusinessInfo = new MyBusinessBusinessInformation.Builder(httpTransport, JsonFactoryUtil.getFactory(), creds).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
MyBusinessBusinessInformation.Accounts accountsList = mybusinessInfo.accounts();
MyBusinessBusinessInformation.Accounts.Locations locations =  accountsList.locations(); 
...

Comment: 3) Loop through MyBusinessAccountManagement accounts and use MyBusinessBusinessInformation to fetch the locations

for( com.google.api.services.mybusinessaccountmanagement.v1.model.Account acct : mgmtAccountsListResp.getAccounts() ) {
    MyBusinessBusinessInformation.Accounts.Locations.List locList = locations.list(acct.getName() );
    locList.setReadMask("name,title,serviceArea,profile,metadata");
 ListLocationsResponse llResp = locList.execute();
    for( com.google.api.services.mybusinessbusinessinformation.v1.model.Location location : llResp.getLocations() ) {
       
    }
}

Comment: 4) Once you have the account (acct) and location (location), then you can use the existing MyBusiness object (v4) to get reviews, but I needed to prefix with account.getName(), where as before I did not
...
MyBusiness mybusiness = new MyBusiness.Builder(httpTransport, JsonFactoryUtil.getFactory(), creds).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
MyBusiness.Accounts.Locations.Reviews.List reviewsList = mybusiness.accounts().locations().reviews().list(acct.getName() + "/" + location.getName());//previously location.getName() was the only param
...